# Split comma and ignore double quotes (from filereader / loaded file - using regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, file, split

I have some data inputs in a form which can receive data from a .txt or .csv file. The code splits the data into commas (,) and any numbers (in order to avoid ID numbers from database files).

I'm using the following regex in my code:

```
var text = textFromFileLoaded.split(/[\,\d]/);
```

Like this it will split all words between commas (\,) and numbers (\d). It works fine. But words between double quotes shouldn't be split. For example:

data in the file: sample-one, sample-two, "sample-three, sample-four", sample-five

And the output is:

```
sample-one | sample-two | "sample-three | sample-four" |
```

and the output should be:

```
sample-one | sample-two | sample-three, sample-four | sample five |
```

I checked many other related questions, and answers usually suggest things like:

```
("\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?")
```

or:

```
(/('[^']+'|[^,]+)/g)
```

But nothing like this has worked so far in my code. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the function's code:

```
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        var text = textFromFileLoaded.split(/[\,\d]/);
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = text[0];
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave2").value = text[1];
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave3").value = text[2];
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave4").value = text[3];
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look: does [this code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dop2oqe2/1/) work for you? (Updated)

Comment: I will also have to fix the save/export function as well, but for now I'm focusing only on the loading part. 
So for testing, load a txt file that contains:
sample-one, sample-two, "sample-three, sample-four", sample-five

Comment: That worked!
http://jsfiddle.net/667rw9df/2/
(it seems to not run on fiddle, but it's working now!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my snippet turned out helpful:

```js
var text = 'sample-one, sample-two, "sample-three, sample-four", sample-five';
var re = /,\s*(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)|\d/g; 
var result = [].map.call(text.split(re), function(el) {
    return el.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
  }
);
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result.join("<br/>");
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

All I did was adding an alternative with a digit to the comma outside quotes regex and removing the initial and final `"` around entries enclosed in double quotes inside a replace callback function.